# Hinges on door are loose

Tags: doors

How can I secure these hinges on the door frame? I need to secure them into the wood of the door. They've loosened over time and screwing them back in fastens it for a few weeks but there isn't enough tension between the screws and the door to hold it in place.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick fix would be to remove the screws and fill the holes with toothpicks and a quality wood glue. Once the glue dries, drill your pilot holes and screw the hinges back into the door.

A better fix would be to remove the screws and drill 3/8" or 7/16" holes into the door and glue in 1" long dowel pins. Then drill your pilot holes and screw the hinges back into the door.

Comment: Most hinge screws are short and small.  Using longer and larger screws after repairing the holes will help also.

Comment: And if you don't have any toothpicks handy, match sticks work too.

Comment: If you can even find wood matches anymore!

Comment: I like to use the toothpick trick, too. Except I don't wait for the glue to dry, I drive the screws into the glue and toothpicks while it's still wet. Leave the door closed for a few hours after that to allow it to set.